# PDFMake - Dynamic pageMargins depending on header's height

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, header, pdfmake

I am dynamically creating a PDF with [PDFMake](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/).

I have a dynamic content (different number of text rows) that is printed on the header and therefore I can't put a fixed value in the `pageMargins` because if the text is too large it will be truncated.

I have tried pre-rendering the header alone and then getting it's height but I feel like I am over-engineering the problem here...

What would be the best solution according to you ?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and since apparently it can't be done dynamically (there's an [open issue with the request](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/368) ), i used negative margin to adjust the pages with different header.

For example: `margin: [0 , -40, 0, 0 ]` will position the object higher.